# Allocate space from NTFS to ext4 with GParted

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I installed Ubuntu on a 20 GB space and now I want more space since my disk is almost full. I downloaded GParted to increase my Ubuntu disk size by decreasing Windows disk. I resized my NTFS disk from 884 GB to 787. With 97 GB, I created a new partition of file system ext4. My partitions are as follows:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGleN.png

Now I want to increase the size of my Ubuntu by those 97 GBs but couldn't find a way to do it. How can I achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

While the partition you want to change (i.e. your Ubuntu partition) is in use (mounted), you can't make many changes to it, especially if those changes involve moving the partition. Of course, with data partitions, you can unmount them and edit them how you wish, but you can't do that with the partition that is currently booted.

The procedure to resizing your Ubuntu partition requires that you have some sort of Linux LiveCD/USB handy. If you have another Linux OS on the drive, **don't** use that. It can cause problems. If you still have your Ubuntu installer lying around somewhere, just skip these steps and continue on with the rest. If you don't have your installer, follow these instructions to create a new one.

---

***USB Method***:

You will need a blank USB flash drive that is at least 4GB.

1. Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run `sudo apt-get install unetbootin`.
2. Once that is done, close the terminal and search for and open the application, **Unetbootin**.
3. Inside **Unetbootin**, select the first option.
4. In the `Select Distribution` dropdown, select `Ubuntu`, and choose `15.10` for the version.
5. Toward the bottom of the window, you will see options for the desired target of the Ubuntu installer. If you only have one flash drive plugged in, **Unetbootin** will have selected it automatically.
6. Click the `Confirm` button near the bottom right of the window to 'burn' Ubuntu to the USB drive.

---

Now that you have an installer disc or USB stick, reboot and boot into it. Choose the `Try Ubuntu without installing.` option when prompted. Once you are in the Live Environment, you can start the procedure to moving your partitions.

1. Search for and open **Gparted** and let it scan your drives.
2. Once you see your partitions, and can interact with them, right click that new `ext4` partition your created.
3. Select the `Delete` option to delete it. ***Please make sure you aren't actually deleting your Ubuntu installation. Delete the 97GB partition.***

   - Now you should have about 97GB unallocated space in that area again.
4. Now, right click the Ubuntu partition and make sure it is unmounted by clicking the `Unmount` option if it exists. If not continue on.
5. In the right-click menu of the Ubuntu partition, select the `Resize/Move` option.
6. In the window that pops up, drag the partition shown at the top of that little window as far left as it can go.
7. Now, drag the right of the partition as far right as it can go, filling up all the space in that little diagram.

   - If there is a little extra space, don't worry about it.
8. Click <kbd>OK</kbd> to exit the window and then click the checkmark button near the top of the window to apply your changes.
9. Let that run and when it's finished, close **Gparted** and reboot.

---

There is a chance Ubuntu won't boot after this. If that happens, use the `boot-repair` ISO from community.ubuntu.com. You'll have to burn it with another computer or from the Live Environment, using **Unetbootin**.

---

If you have any questions, comment. Sorry for the rushed ending. I have to leave for a while.

Answer (score 1):

You can't move this space until you remove the active partitions, those where your system runs. Sectors can't be moved to a space after the running partition scheme. I had this problem, and the only way to repair it was a clean install on a new partition scheme without deleting my Win partition. Not a Linux problem, is just physics on data stored on hard drives.

Please, anyone correct me if I'm giving a wrong approach on that.

Comment: There is an easier way. I'm writing something up now.