# Increasing Ubuntu /boot partition size in a dual boot

Tags: 16.04, partitioning, gparted

I have a dual boot with Windows 7 and Ubuntu 16.04.

Each time I want to install something in Ubuntu, or upgrade to 18.04. Ubuntu says I don't have enough space. Even after `sudo apt autoremove`.

SO I want to increase the size of my `/boot` partition.

Below is a screenshot of gparted.

[image: many small partitions]

Do I increase the `/boot` partition by taking space from the Linux-swap partition or do I take space from the `/dev/sda7` NTFS partition?

What would be the ideal way to go about this?

Screenshot of my `/boot` contents as asked in the comments:

[image: files for only 2 kernels]

Comment: Seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) for several reasons. 1) Such a small install should not require separate /boot and swap in the first place. The default install of Ubuntu 18.04, for example,  creates neither anymore. 2) Your /boot seems adequately sized for normal operation - the requirement to resize likely indicates accumulating kernels, which is easily cured several simpler ways.

Comment: My actual problem is that each time i want to install something or upgrade to 18.04. Ubuntu tells me i don't have adequate space. sudo apt autoremove does remove the old kernels but still there isn't adequate space. So I would naturally want to extend my /boot partition

Comment: Why do you have so much swap space allocated?!? Also is this a new problem? Or has it been this way since install? You may just need to inspect what's actually in `/boot`

Comment: I didn't personally partition all of this. I was given this laptop. And no, I didn't face this problem from the beginning. Only until recently. And I decided to ask once I tried upgrading to 18.04 and failed because of inadequate space :(

Comment: I personally have 8G of swap and this feels like way to much. I rarely ever touch it and when I do its never more than 1G. So take some space from there. But this seems more like a band-aid rather than a fix. Post the contents of `/boot` and we can see what's really eating up all that space.

Comment: Added the screenshot of /boot in the question! @j-money

Comment: I don't see any red flags for installation of programs from what you have posted:  Can you attempt to install something and capture the error messages?  Please copy and paste the text, rather than doing a screenshot and pasting an image!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got your issue I think you should take space from ntfs partition and add it to your /boot point for more information regarding how to allocate space from ntfs to ext4 please refer this answer [Allocate ntfs to ext4 using gparted](https://askubuntu.com/q/747509/644754)

If you have any otyer doubts feel free to ask in comments.